# Reflection for Class of generic parameter in Java?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, types

Imagine the following scenario:

```
class MyClass extends OtherClass<String>{

   String myName;
   //Whatever

}

class OtherClass<T> {

   T myfield;

}
```

And I am analyzing MyClass using reflection specifically `(MyClass.class).getDeclaredFields()`, in this case I will get the following fields (and Types, using getType() of the Field):

```
myName --> String
myField --> T
```

I want to get the actual Type for T, which is known at runtime due to the explicit "String" in the extends notation, how do I go about getting the non-genetic type of myField?

EDIT RESOLVED:

Seems like the answer is "you can't".    For those who may look at this question later I'd recommend using Jackson (I was trying to do this to generate JSON) and annotating your classes and fields in such a way so that Jackson is aware of the inheritance hierarchy and can automatically do what the correct answer below suggested.

Comment: The answer is not that you can't; you can easily create a map from type parameters to explicit type arguments.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This can be achieved with reflection only because you explicitly used `String`, otherwise this information would've been lost due to type erasure.

```
ParameterizedType t = (ParameterizedType) MyClass.class.getGenericSuperclass(); // OtherClass<String>
Class<?> clazz = (Class<?>) t.getActualTypeArguments()[0]; // Class<String>
```

Comment: Looks like you win the competition for the complete answer :)

Comment: This is a great answer, however how can I do this in general with a Field object?  I don't want to explicitly ask for the super class because I am just trying to get all of the Declared Fields of my sub-class, one of which happens to be the generic.  I just want something similar to getDeclaredFields(), but smarter about generics.   Does that make sense?

Comment: @hatboysam One way or the other you have to ask for the super class. Calling `Field.getGenericParameter` will only ever return the type parameter (in this case `T`), not the explicit type argument (`String`). You can take this type parameter and find the explicit type argument by creating a map from `MyClass.class.getSuperclass().getTypeArguments()` to `MyClass.class.getGenericSuperclass().getActualTypeArguments()`.

Comment: Carefully with the casting. In general, it may be a Class, or a TypeVariable. In which case you need to check the Bounds.

Answer (score 4):

I found a nice explanation [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/generics.html):

> When runtime inspecting a parameterizable type itself, like java.util.List, there is no way of knowing what type is has been parameterized to. This makes sense since the type can be parameterized to all kinds of types in the same application. But, when you inspect the method or field that declares the use of a parameterized type, you can see at runtime what type the paramerizable type was parameterized to.

In short:

You cannot see on a type itself what type it is parameterized to a runtime, but you can see it in fields and methods where it is used and parameterized.

In code:

You can't see `T` here:

```
class MyClass<T> { T myField; }
```

You can see the "`T`" here:

```
class FooClass {
    MyClass<? extends Serializable> fooField;
}
```

Here you would be able to tell the type and type parameters of `fooField`.
See `getGeneric*()` methods of `Class` and `Method`.

By the way, I often see this (shortened):

```
Class fieldArgClass = (Class) aType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

This is not correct, because `getActualTypeArguments()` may, and often will, return `TypeVariable` instead of class - that's when the generic is `<? extends SomeClass>` instead of just `<SomeClass>`. It can go deeper, imagine:

```
class FooClass {
    MyClass<? extends Map<String, List<? extends Serializable>>> fooField;
}
```

So you get a tree of `Type`s. But that's a bit off-topic. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic example of why reflection is not a great idea.

**What you can get from a program by reflection are only those facts that the compiler people for the language chose to make available.**

And they generally can't afford to make everything available; they'd sort of have to keep the raw program text around.

All the other facts about your code are thus not available to the reflectee.

The cure for this is to step *outside* the language and use a tool that *can* provide any arbitrary bit of information about the code.  Such tools are called [Program Transformation Systems (PTS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation).

A PTS parses the source code and builds an AST the represents it.  A good PTW will build an AST that holds essentially everything about the code (operators, operands, punctuation, comments) so that it can be inspected.  Normally a PTS will record the line/column position of language tokens so even layout information is available; extreme PTS will record the whitespace in the gaps between tokens or at least know how to read the original text file when necessary if asked about it.   This AST is in essence the equivalent of the full text I said would be necessary, but in a more convenient form to process.

(PTSs have one other very nice property: they can *modify* the AST and regenerate code for the modified program.  But that is above and beyond reflection so I won't comment further on this aspect).

Answer (score 0):

Generic types are *not* known at runtime. Only the compiler knows about them, checks that your program is typed correctly, and then removes them.

In your particular case, calling `MyClass.class.getGenericSuperclass()` might give you the information you need, because for some strange reason, the concrete types used when inheriting are kept in the class descriptor.

Comment: It's not "some strange reason". *Declarations* of fields, methods, superclasses, enclosing classes, etc. are always kept, because other classes need to use them when compiling. This is a separate issue from the runtime types of objects, where there are no generics.

Answer (score 0):

greate work around [here](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html). it is call the "Gafters Gadget" pattern. it is used by jackson and google libraries such as guava.

/**
 * References a generic type.
 *
 * @author crazybob@google.com (Bob Lee)
 */

```
public abstract class TypeReference {
```

`private final Type type;
private volatile Constructor<?> constructor;

protected TypeReference() {
    Type superclass = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    if (superclass instanceof Class) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Missing type parameter.");
    }
    this.type = ((ParameterizedType) superclass).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}

/**
 * Instantiates a new instance of {@code T} using the default, no-arg
 * constructor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public T newInstance()
        throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException,
               InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
    if (constructor == null) {
        Class<?> rawType = type instanceof Class<?>
            ? (Class<?>) type
            : (Class<?>) ((ParameterizedType) type).getRawType();
        constructor = rawType.getConstructor();
    }
    return (T) constructor.newInstance();
}

/**
 * Gets the referenced type.
 */
public Type getType() {
    return this.type;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> l1 = new TypeReference<ArrayList<String>>() {}.newInstance();
    List l2 = new TypeReference<ArrayList>() {}.newInstance();
}`

}

Answer (score -5):

There is no direct way to get the actual type because of the [Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). However you can use the following way:

in your `OtherClass<T>`, write the following abstract method:

```
protected abstract class<T> getClazz();
```

Then in `MyClass`, you implement the method:

```
@Override
protected Class<String> getClazz(){
    return String.class;
}
```

then you can call `getClazz()` to get the class.

Comment: The OP gave a concrete type parameter for his generic class, that information *is* kept at runtime and can be retrieved.

Comment: -1 - This solution is unnecessary like others noted on this post. Also, your `getClass()` would have a name clash with the final method [`Object#getClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass\(\))

Comment: @Jeffrey, using your method, you can get the type in `MyClass`, but you cannot get it in `OtherClass`