# Is retrieving the generic parameter of a class using the reflection method guaranteed to work (in my case)?

Tags: java, events, generics, reflection

Alright, so I'm trying to design an event system for myself, and this is what I have so far for an event handler (Event is some empty class):

```
public interface EventHandler
{
    public Class<? extends Event> type();

    public void handle(Event event);
}
```

The goal is that an EventHandler can only handle one type of event (at this point).
But, I wonder if I could reformat it like this:

```
public interface EventHandler <T extends Event>
{
    public void handle(T event);
}
```

This would help me in two ways:

- The need for `type()` is gone.
- I wouldn't have to cast while handling events.

Based on this question: [Reflection for Class of generic parameter in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164756/reflection-for-class-of-generic-parameter-in-java), I can get `T` by this method:

```
ParameterizedType t = (ParameterizedType) MyClass.class.getGenericSuperclass(); //OtherClass<String>
Class<?> clazz = (Class<?>) t.getActualTypeArguments()[0]; // Class<String>
```

I am aware that Type Erasure is a factor when dealing with stuff like this, but what I don't understand is when it would apply to my use of `EventHandler<T>`, or pretty much at all to be honest. For example, the only way I would use `EventHandler<T>` is:

```
public class TestEvent extends Event {}

public class TestEventHandler implements EventHandler<TestEvent>
{
    @Override
    public void handle(TestEvent event)
    {
        System.out.println("Event Handled");
    }
}
```

(my Events would be in their own package, and the handlers would be in another)

The soon-to-be event bus would register this handler by class and get the generic Event type of it to use as a key in a map of Event classes and EventHandlers.

Anyways, any clarification would be appreciated. If I could only get the generic type like half the time or something, it wouldn't work out, and I'd probably have to do a version without generic types. Feel free to criticize how EventHandler is formatted to begin with in your answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reflection trick is also used for type tokens (look 'em up).

Here's an example of [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) occurrence

```
public class Generic<TypeParameter> {
    public void method(TypeParameter parameter) {
        // no way to know the type bound to TypeParameter due to Type Erasure
    }
}
```

But it doesn't apply to your case. A declaration like

```
public class TestEventHandler extends EventHandler<TestEvent>
```

is very explicit. It uses `TestEvent` as a type argument for the generic `EventHandler` type. What's more, the method declaration

```
@Override
public void handle(TestEvent event)
{
    System.out.println("Event Handled");
}
```

also tells us that the parameter is of type `TestEvent`. This information is not lost at runtime. It's part of the `Class` information (it's in the byte code).

If you keep using making your `EventHandler` types like your `TestEventHandler`, you'll be able to use the reflection trick to get the `Event` type. Note that you could also use anonymous subclasses

```
new EventHandler<TestEvent>() {/*body*/};
```

to achieve the same thing.

Comment: thanks for the quick explanation, but one more question: you said that `public class TestEventHandler extends EventHandler<TestEvent>` was "explicit". Let's say I made an example that wasn't explicit, would that be something like `public class TestEventHandler<T extends TestEvent> extends EventHandler <T>`? (don't ask me why I would even do something like that)

Comment: @Octopod I was just using the word _explicit_ to emphasize that the you know what type you're working with. In the `TestEventHandler` in your comment, you're working with a type variable. There's no way to know its value (the type bound) _within_ the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

The code you showed relies on `MyClass` being a direct implementing class of `EventHandler`, and that `MyClass` implements `EventHandler`'s type parameter with a concrete class as the type argument. So it must be something like this:

```
class MyClass implements EventHandler<String>
```

Most of the time where this is used (e.g. with type tokens), the user is expected to create an anonymous class which directly implements `EventHandler<String>` like this: `new EventHandler<String>() { /* body of anonymous class, can be empty */ }`, which is equivalent to the name type above except for the anonymous part.

Some scenarios where the code will not work:

- If `MyClass` is generic and implements `EventHandler` with a type variable as the type argument instead of a concrete class:

  ```
  class MyClass<T> implements EventHandler<T>
  ```
- If `MyClass` does not directly implement `EventHandler`, but goes through one or more non-generic classes in between:

  ```
  class MyClass implements YourClass
  class YourClass implements EventHandler<String>
  ```

(in this latter case, it would be possible for smart code to traverse the type hierarchy to find the argument with which `EventHandler` is implemented, but it would need to be very complicated to handle all the cases, e.g. `YourClass` could itself be generic, and use one of its parameters to implement `EventHandler`)