# How can I set a dynamic Custom Java Object in generic Interface during run time

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android. I have a task that download generic object from a server api and save it to a specific Object at runtime inside a loop.

**Example:** I have an Objects of **Car**, **Bottle**, **Animal**.

It is it possible to change this `DownloadCallback<Object>` during runtime?

```
  while (!finish) {
     retrofitHandler.downloadData("accounts", "1", new DownloadCallBack<Object>() {
         @Override
         public void onResponse(GenericResponse<Object> response) {

         }
         @Override
         public void onFailure(String response) {

         }
       });
  }
```

I know the Generic Class in set at Compile Time. but is this possible?

Comment: i don't think that's possible. Instead, you can just use object type and cast it to custom object in runtime.

Comment: @MehranZamani, thanks for your comments. I heard of Reflection. do you think it is possible to that approach?

Comment: I haven't been worked with Reflection so don't know if it's going to help you with that. there are some answers in SO that you can check out. [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164756/reflection-for-class-of-generic-parameter-in-java) and [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901164/get-type-of-a-generic-parameter-in-java-with-reflection) and [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime).

Comment: @MehranZamani Thanks man.

Comment: I made the changes on my API. which will now return one object(Generic). then on Android. i'll consume it as List<Map<String, Object>> but it takes a lot of time when iterating the data.