# How to do use java reflection to determine generic type of base class field

Tags: java, reflection

I know that if I have a field with generic type arguments such as this

```
List<String> mList
```

if I can get a reference to the field, I can use this code to determine that the generic type is actually a String:

```
((ParameterizedType field.getGenericType()).getActualTypeArguments()
```

However, my problem is a bit more complicated. We have a superclass that looks something like this:

```
abstract class CustomList extends List<T> {
  List<T> mList;    
}
```

Then we have another class that looks something like this:

```
class FooList extends CustomList<Foo> {
  //...
}
```

When I try and reflect on the field mList, it tells me that that generic type parameter is T. Is there any way to determine that it's actually of type Foo? If I could determine that the FooList class has a generic parameter Foo, that would probably be good enough, but I'm not sure how to do that either?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164756/reflection-for-class-of-generic-parameter-in-java

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to compile, but check [fasterxml classmate](https://github.com/FasterXML/java-classmate)

Comment: @zlakad. Thanks.  I'll look through that post - it does seem to address this problem. Didn't find it when I was looking earlier. If you post that as an answer, I can mark it as accepted. Thanks again

Comment: @MenachemSchachter You're welcome. I don't really care about reputation so, let it be this way. Thank you, too... and good luck, friend.

Answer (score 0):

In fact stackoverflow.com/questions/11164756/ doesn't resolve your problem.

You want to infer the `List.T` from `FooList`, not `CustomList.T`.

You can use my utility class [`GenericUtil`](https://github.com/XDean/Java-EX/blob/297b21df13ebe25e991ec3741af21b3592e92375/src/main/java/xdean/jex/util/reflect/GenericUtil.java)

```
getGenericTypes(FooList.class, List.class); // return {Foo.class}
```

And it can handle any type generic not only class type.